# Too many parameters error - exceeding the limit of 255 words eligible for method parameters in Drools?

Tags: drools

I am using Drools for my Project here I am unable to pass more than 255 arguments in method signature if the arguments will exceed 255 it is throwing below error. Can any one help me how to resolve the issue ?

java.lang.ClassFormatError: Too many arguments in method signature in class file com/hra/rules/Person
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.drools.rule.JavaDialectRuntimeData$PackageClassLoader.fastFindClass(JavaDialectRuntimeData.java:615)
        at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader$CachingLoader.load(CompositeClassLoader.java:254)
        at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader$CachingLoader.load(CompositeClassLoader.java:237)
        at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader.loadClass(CompositeClassLoader.java:88)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.drools.base.ClassTypeResolver.resolveType(ClassTypeResolver.java:155)
        at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.processTypeDeclarations(PackageBuilder.java:2049)
        at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.mergePackage(PackageBuilder.java:1218)
        at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackage(PackageBuilder.java:829)
        at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:467)
        at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:673)
        at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:45)
        at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:34)
        at com.sample.DroolsTest.readKnowledgeBase(DroolsTest.java:601)
        at com.sample.DroolsTest.main(DroolsTest.java:45)

Comment: Makes me wonder that in what case does one have more than 255 arguments to a method? Maybe there's something to refactor in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Which Drools version are you using? What you have described was [a known bug in drool](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-3621)s that should be solved in 5.5.0.

Hope it helps,